# Using ctrl-backspace to remove previous word in MATLAB command window

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts, command-window

I use ctrl-backspace in MATLAB Editor (MATLAB 2015a) to remove the previous word, but it doesn't work in the command window. I tried changing it in Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, but there doesn't seem to be the option to bind it to "Remove Previous Word" in the Command Window. In the attached image, you can see that it is set to work in the MATLAB Editor, but when clicking the down-arrow next to where it says MATLAB Editor, it does not show any other options.

This seems like a very common shortcut used by many Windows programs, and it's strange that it should only be allowed in the editor. If it's actually not allowed, why? Is there a workaround?

I tried to post an image of this but stack overflow says I'm not yet cool enough.

Comment: You could always use ctrl-shift-leftArrow followed by backspace. Sounds like a lot of work but it's not, you end up doing it automatically

Comment: @LuisMendo - I do `Ctrl+Shift+LeftArrow` without thinking all the time.  It's second nature lol.

Comment: That _does_ work, but it doesn't make sense why the easier thing isn't allowed. It works in the editor, for example. Good suggestions though!

Comment: @rayryeng Same here. To write my comment, I had to type some text and remove a word, looking carefully at the keys. It's so automatic I don't even know the keys I'm pressing when I do it:-D